# Python StreamRequestHandler

Tags: python, sockets

So i've got a socket server running the StreamRequestHandler class. The problem lies in writing back to the socket. MY client does not seem to receive the data.

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler)
  def handle(self):
    while 1:
      self.data = self.rfile.readline()
      ...process data and pref result...
      self.wfile.write(result)
      break
```

this seems straight forward, what am i missing. Is there a way to flush the send buffer, as the amount of data i send is very little?

Comment: Did you try `self.wfile.flush()`?

Comment: I'm actually going to try and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: I suppose your while loop doesn't really break after one run?

Comment: For what it's worth I'm seeing similar problems.  My first message is going out, but subsequent messages are not.  First thought was to add the flush() and still no luck.

Comment: send newline from your client. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718439/reading-data-send-from-streamrequesthandler-write

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading data send from StreamRequestHandler write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718439/reading-data-send-from-streamrequesthandler-write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have problems with sending data from the server to the client. I had the same problem. Turns out, `wfile` and `rfile` are of type BytesIO and take only binary data.

So if your `result` is a normal string, you'll have to make it binary.

`bstring = b"your string"`

`bstring = bytes("normal string", "utf8")`

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler)
  def handle(self):
    while 1:
      self.data = self.rfile.readline()
      if not self.data:
          break
      self.wfile.write(b"Got some data\n")
```